# How to update values for custom owner to standard

Tags: workflow

I have a **user owner custom LOOKUP field on contact object**.As soon as I update the user owner field,the value should be reflected on the standard owner field.

How is  it possible.

Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use process builder for this functionality. Create process builder some thing like below:
[image]

Comment: I want to use workflow rather using process builder

Comment: in workflow you cannot use a reference of a field , you would need to select a user by default.